# Django: call python function when clicking on button

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

Let's say that I have a python function that only sends email to myself, that I want to call whenever the user clicks on a button in a template, without any redirection (maybe just a popup messege).

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You need ajax for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send an email without reloading the page you might want to send a request with ajax. [Here](https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/jquery-ajax-methods/) are some details.

For example, you could write the following ajax function:

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
$.ajax({
url: '/send_mail/',
data: {email: 'send'},
type: 'GET',
}).done(function() {
alert('Well done!')
});
});
```

And in a view you can handle it almost as a simple request:

```
from django.http import Http404

...
if request.is_ajax():
    if request.GET.get('email') == 'send':
        # send email
    else:
        raise Http404
```

Answer (score 0):

In your views you can handle any incoming get/post requests. And based on handler for that button (and this button obviously must send something to server) you can call any function.